# How can I change cursor color in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to change the cursor colour in the Visual Studio Code editor window?

I am slightly colour blind, so I would like to change it from red to something else (*yellow maybe*) to improve accessibility and make it easier for me to read.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Try adding this to your global preferences file:

```js
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorCursor.foreground": "#ffff00",
    "terminalCursor.foreground": "#ffff00"
}
```

Also worth noting that if you're colourblind, there are probably some colourblind-friendly themes for vscode out there, though I can't say I have looked for them myself.

Comment: This doesn't work on version 1.69.2

Comment: You may need to make the preference more specific if you are using a custom theme so you basically override the custom theme as for example here: https://pastebin.com/zsRf8jLg @Ivan

Comment: @Ivan I just used this in 1.77.3 successfully.

Comment: Note that foreground and background settings are swapped. I.e. the text under the cursor has background color.