# Is it possible to change color of pointer to cursor location in scrollbar

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Is it possible to change color of this pointer to cursor location? Now it correlates with my cursor color, is it possible to change it independently from my cursor color?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the color of the vertical scroll bar on the right side of VScode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71302704/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-vertical-scroll-bar-on-the-right-side-of-vscode)

Comment: @Vega This isn't a duplicate of that question.  This is asking about the cursor location indicator in the scrollbar (the green line in the screenshot), not the scrollbar itself.  But, there does not seem to be a way to change these independently. I'd suggest making a feature request on the github for VS Code https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: @TimothyG. then this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50200924/5468463

Comment: @Vega I'd still say no.  That's for the cursor itself - not the indicator on the scrollbar.  While the setting discussed in that post controls both, this posts want to know if you can change ONLY the scrollbar indicator, which doesn't appear possible currently.

Answer (score 2):

> Now it correlates with my cursor color, is it possible to change it independently from my cursor color?

At the time of this writing, I'm not aware of a way to do this. It seems tied to the `editorCursor.foreground` colour customization point, which I find surprising, though somewhat understandable. If you want a `editorOverviewRuler` colour customization point for this, you can [raise a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) or a PR implementing it.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket or PR like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Comment: I made this ticket:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/204621